# How to enable hot swap in IntelliJ webapp without having to rebuild?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, hotswap

When I was working on Eclipse on my code and had hot swap turned on, I was able to make a small change in a file and on save it would hot swap that code and my server would run with the new code. However, I can't seem to mimic that in IntelliJ

I have turned on the hot swap in my web app, but it does not hot swap any code immediately. I have to be in debug mode and rebuild the entire project for the code to be swapped. Is there a way to mimic the Eclipse functionality in IntelliJ? I want to be able to work faster instead of having to rebuild my entire project every time I make the smallest change.

Comment: If you're using some application server for running the application try to modify run/debug configuration settings as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html Select `Update classes and resources` or `Hot swap classes` under `On frame deactivation` and `On 'Update' action`